# stopPropagation combined with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, stoppropagation

I am trying to avoid event stop propagation at React but it is not working.

Here is my snippet of code:

```
{this.state.telephone && this.state.telephone.map((el, index) => 
   <div className="left contactto-100">
      <Telephone onChange={this.handlePhone} value={el} counter={index} />
      {index > 0 ? 
         <div className="left" data-pos={index} onClick={this.removePhone}>
            <Delete className="list-table-body-action-icons" width="28" height="28"/>
         </div> 
       : null}
   </div>
)}
```

Delete is a svg component:

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'

class Delete extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <svg className={this.props.className} fill="#666" width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <path d="M12,14H50v2H12V14Zm28,1H38V12a2,2,0,0,0-2-2H26a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v3H22V12a4,4,0,0,1,4-4H36a4,4,0,0,1,4,4v3ZM25,20l1,32L24,52,23,20Zm12,0L39,20,38,52,36,52Zm-7,0h2V52H30V20ZM41,58H21a4.06,4.06,0,0,1-4-3.88l-3-39,2-.15,3,39A2.1,2.1,0,0,0,21,56H41a2.18,2.18,0,0,0,2-2.12l3-39,2,0.15-3,39A4.16,4.16,0,0,1,41,58Z"/>
            </svg>
        );
    }
}

Delete.defaultProps = { width: '24', height: '24', className:''}

Delete.PropTypes = {
    width: React.PropTypes.string,
    height: React.PropTypes.string,
    className: React.PropTypes.string
}

export default Delete
```

and here is `removePhone` function:

```
removePhone(event){
        console.log(event.target)
        let pos = event.target.getAttribute("data-pos")
        if(pos > 0){
           this.state.telephone.splice(pos, 1)
           this.state.phoneValidator.splice(pos, 1)
           this.setState({
             telephone: this.state.telephone,
             phoneValidator: this.state.phoneValidator
           })
         }

        event.stopPropagation()
        event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()    
    }
```

When I click at `<div className="left" data-pos={index} onClick={this.removePhone}>`

the console shows me svg, path (inside svg) and when is out of svg area appears the div.

I tried `event.stopPropagation` and `event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation`

And I set bind to the `removePhone` function:

```
this.removePhone = this.removePhone.bind(this)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is your `removePhone` function actually do? why do you need `event.target` ?

Comment: I will edit my removePhone, I need event.target because I have to remove one specific element from my state